# activeCount method shows one active thread even when all the threads complete there execution

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import threading
import sys

class mythread (threading.Thread) :

    def __init__(self,thread_id,argument) :
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.argument = argument

    def run(self) :
        for i in range(5) :
            print(self.thread_id,self.argument) 
try :

    thread1 = mythread("T1","arg1")
    thread2 = mythread("T2","arg2")
    thread3 = mythread("T3","arg3")
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()

    while threading.activeCount() != 0 :
        #print(threading.enumerate())
        pass

    print("Completed")
except :
    print("Cannot start the thread")
```

I want to print the "completed statement" after completing the execution of all the threads but the `threading.activeCount()` keeps showing that there is one active thread even though when all the threads print out all the statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of the `threading` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#module-threading):

> `threading.active_count()`
>
> Return the number of `Thread` objects currently alive. The returned count is equal to the length of the list returned by `enumerate()`.
>
> `threading.enumerate()`
>
> Return a list of all `Thread` objects currently alive. The list includes daemonic threads, dummy thread objects created by `current_thread()`, **and the main thread**. It excludes terminated threads and threads that have not yet been started.

So, `threading.active_count()` returns the number of threads that includes the main thread. Thus, this number will always be greater or equal to *one*.